# Code to take snapshot of a html page?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

I want to know the way to make snapshot of a webpage through code. I don't need any external servers or something to do the stuff. The work should be done through html coding. I can't figure out how HTML-Canvas will help this problem.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Comment: I surfed the net. All i got is link to some websites that takes the screenshot of the given page url. I want to do it by code.